# How to open App via AppIntents conditionally?

Tags: swiftui, appintents

I am currently creating an `App` which is supposed to launch via an AppIntent. For example whenever I open *Instagram* it should trigger the AppIntent, which then decides if my App is supposed to open or not. The first part already works fine via Apple Shortcuts.
The problem is dynamically **opening** or *not opening* my `App`. Unfortunately the openAppWhenRun field is supposed to be static and cannot be computed at runtime.

Here is the AppIntent so far:

```
struct OpenTimeEfficientIntent: AppIntent {
    
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Opens the app conditionally"
    static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = false
    @Parameter(title: "OpenedApp", optionsProvider: Provider())
    var app: String //this is the initially opened app e.g. Instagram (i want to pass it)
    
    @MainActor
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult & ProvidesDialog {
        //at this point I want to decide, whether the app should be launched or not
    }
}
```

Just to specify: I don't want to decide which view I want to open but rather if I want to open the `App` at all.

### What did I try?

I already tried to open the app via Deeplinks which is not allowed on iOS as the AppIntent is just a background task: `The App is neither visible nor entitled, so may not perform un-trusted user actions`

Trying to set the `openAppWhenRun` dynamically didn't work either.

### For context

The app is basically a confirmation dialog. When I press *no*, the app closes and nothing happens. When I press *yes*, Instagram would be opened again. But in that case I don't want to launch my app again to prevent being stuck in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you adopt `ForegroundContinuableIntent` rather than `AppIntent`, it will run in the background until you indicate it needs to open your app in the `perform` function. This allows you to conditionally decide whether you want to open your app.

```
@available(iOS 16.4, *)
struct OpenTimeEfficientIntent: ForegroundContinuableIntent {
    
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Opens the app conditionally"
    static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = false

    @Parameter(title: "OpenedApp", optionsProvider: Provider())
    var app: String //this is the initially opened app e.g. Instagram (i want to pass it)
    
    @MainActor
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult & ProvidesDialog {
        //at this point you can decide whether the app should be brought to the foreground or not

        // Stop performing the app intent and ask the user to continue to open the app in the foreground
        throw needsToContinueInForegroundError()

        // You can customize the dialog and/or provide a closure to do something in your app after it's opened
        throw needsToContinueInForegroundError("Please continue to open the app.") {
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "yourapp://deeplinktocontent")!)
        }

        // Or you could ask the user to continue performing the intent in the foreground - if they cancel the intent stops, if they continue the intent execution resumes with the app open
        // This API also accepts an optional dialog and continuation closure
        try await requestToContinueInForeground()
        return .result(dialog: "I opened the app.")
    }

}
```

Comment: This seems like a good approach. Do you know if it is possible to decide whether to open the app, without the user needing to decide? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: @Meyssam I don't believe so, as of now each of these requires the user confirm they want to continue to open the app.

Comment: Does this answer will help me build a functionality like this app :https://apps.apple.com/app/one-sec-screen-time-focus/id1532875441?platform=iphone 

I want user to tap on "Continue to Instagram" or Close This App as conditions when AppIntent is run ... ( I have different app use case )

Comment: I think the standard options don't allow you to close the respective app.