# How to Dynamically Open App with AppIntent

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, appintents

I am trying to dynamically determine whether the AppIntent opens the app, as dictated by the `openAppWhenRun` property. Sometimes it should open the app and sometimes it shouldn't.

**What I have tried**

1. I tried having nested AppIntents so the main AppIntent would either run the AppIntent which opens the app or run the AppIntent which doesn't. However, it gave me the following error: `Function declares an opaque return type 'some IntentResult & OpensIntent', but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types`

```
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult & OpensIntent {
        if (condition) {
                return .result(opensIntent: OtherIntent())
        }
            
        return .result(opensIntent: NestedIntent())
    }
```

2. I tried making `openAppWhenRun` not static and changing it at runtime but this didn't work

It's important to note that I also don't want to use `needsToContinueInForegroundError()` or `requestToContinueInForeground()` since they require user confirmation.

Comment: had the exact same problem today and didn't find a solution. The ForegroundContinuableIntent is also no option for me.

Comment: @Luke I've spent multiple days looking for a solution with no success. However, it definitely seems to be possible since I use apps that offer the functionality. Hopefully someone has some insight on this.

Comment: @Hydrone I'm very interested - which apps achieve this functionality?

Comment: @RoyRodney I've seen a few apps which seem to be able to do this. One example is called ClearSpace

Answer (score 2):

I kind of fixed the problem, even though I didn't manage to get it working within one AppIntent.

I created two AppIntents one which returns a boolean and is set to **openAppWhenRun = false:**

```
import AppIntents
import UIKit

struct CheckAppIntent: AppIntent {
  
  static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Check Open App"
  
  static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = false
  
  @MainActor
  func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult & ReturnsValue<Bool> {
    let shouldOpenApp = true
    return .result(
      value: shouldOpenApp)
  }
}
```

The second Intent which only opens the app:

```
import AppIntents
import UIKit

struct OpenAppIntent: AppIntent {
  
  static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Open App"
  
  static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = true
  
  @MainActor
  func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
    return .result()
  }
}
```

These AppIntents are than linked together in a shortcut within an if-statement.
In my case, I made the Shortcut available for users to download

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is caused by [trying to return different types as `some Type`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433665/what-is-the-some-keyword-in-swiftui)

This is the same sort of thing a @ViewBuilder takes care of in SwiftUI by wrapping the results in a single type. However, since this concerns static properties, a wrapper type (I believe) can't work here.

So it seems you can't call different intent types based on a condition. [This discussion would also indicate what you are asking for is impossible.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76500378/how-to-open-app-via-appintents-conditionally)

Now you can of course, chain intents. But as far as I'm aware, the only way to break this chain is by throwing an error. This gives us one incredibly hacky solution:

```
enum DoneError: Error, LocalizedError {
    case done
    var errorDescription: String?  { "All done!" }
}

func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
    // do things...
    if condition {
        throw DoneError.done
    } else {
        return .result(opensIntent: OpeningAppIntent())
    }
}
```

...so you should probably just label the intents differently.

Comment: Throwing an error was one of the other strategies I attempted and although it gets 90% of the desired functionality, the main issue is that it displays this error to the user every time which isn't ideal.